# Prerequisite books before Hungerford's Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Prerequisite books before Hungerford's graduate Algebra?

I have an pdf version of the book and feel the Hungerford is overcomplicated after i finish some of the books title with something like first course in abstract algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hungerford has two books on Algebra. The one you mention is meant as a book for a graduate course. Typically students taking this class will have had some exposure to Abstract Algebra. As a first introduction to the subject, this would not necessarily be the best book to read.

Hungerford also published Abstract Algebra: An Introduction, aimed at undergraduate students. This book is a bit gentler. Also this book examines Rings and Fields and then later covers Group theory. This is reverse of most books on the subject.

Another undergraduate Abstract Algebra book is Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra. I used this book when I was an undergraduate. I strongly recommend it.

In graduate school, my introductory class used Dummit and Foote's "Abstract Algebra." It is quite a large book, and covers many topics. Some of the instructors used it for a comprehensive two year course.

Dover Publications also has a bunch of abstract algebra books for cheap. I would sift through the amazon reviews to see if you can find a good one there.

Finally a classic textbook on the subject is Herstein's "Topics in Algebra." I haven't read it myself, but I have heard that it is excellent.

---

By the way, Gallian is in its 8th edition now. Previous editions are more than sufficient for your needs, since it seems you are on a course of self study. I used the 6th edition, personally. That edition can be purchased used for under ten dollars right now on amazon.